# failed to load source: unsupported URL when trying a post request

Tags: ajax, mongodb, post, routes

I'm trying to use a simple post request on a route on top of a mongo DB.
my js file (I combined the router with the app) looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
app.use(express.static('public'));
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
if (err) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
} else {
  console.log('Connection established to', url);


  //Close connection
  //db.close();
```

}});

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Got a POST request');
});

app.listen(27017,function(){
console.log("Server started successfully at Port 27017!");
});
```

on my html file I simple have a section like this (yes, my post request doesn't do much for now):

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "localhost:27017/test/",

});

I can't seem to get it to work, my console keeps throwing: "[Error] Failed to load resource: unsupported URL (localhost:27017/test/, line 0)"
at me, and when I try to browse directly to the url via my browser I'm getting a "Cannot GET /test/" message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is your app listening on the same port as mongo? don't do this (I'm not sure it's even possible). second, you don't have any route for `test`.

Comment: Thank you for that! I have changed the to app.listen(3000,... and the url to "/" and I'm now getting "Failed to load resource: file is directory". I think I'm missing something around the directory structure on my local (I'm saving the app and the index.html in two different places). Can that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me in the end:
1. Changed the app to listen to 3000 (or any other port that my DB server wasn't listening to). Thanks TomG.
2.changed router.post to app.post (you can use expressing routing but I had a mistake there).